# setting for the reading serial port in c++

Tags: c++, serial-port

I have a little problem with the setting of the parameters for the serial. In the program c++ I configured:
- the baud rate   -> 38400
- the data bits   -> 8
- the  parity     -> none
- the stop bits   -> 1
- the handshaking -> none.
But the buffer for reading from the serial is dirty, it contains more messages. I want 1 message for 1 buffer. Can you help me? I wait answer .
This is the code:

```
speed=B38400;
    cfsetospeed (&tty, speed);
    cfsetispeed (&tty, speed);

    tty.c_cflag = (tty.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8;     // 8-bit chars
    // disable IGNBRK for mismatched speed tests; otherwise receive break
    // as \000 chars
    tty.c_iflag &= ~IGNBRK;         // disable break processing
    tty.c_lflag = 0;                // no signaling chars, no echo,
                                    // no canonical processing
    tty.c_oflag = 0;                // no remapping, no delays
    tty.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;            // read doesn't block
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;            // 0.5 seconds read timeout

    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); // shut off xon/xoff ctrl

    tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);// ignore modem controls,
                                    // enable reading
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);      // shut off parity
    tty.c_cflag |= parity;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
```

Comment: What platform are you using?  There is no standard C++ code for serial ports; they are all platform dependent.

Answer (score -1):

I use the raspberry ,a debian platform